# Algorithm indent problem with sig-alternate document & algorithm(ic) package

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

Can anyone tell me why the indention of the algorithm does not work?

I have the following code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{STEP 1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE Something
\FOR{\textbf{each} $user$}
    \IF{A in B is $>$ 0}
        \STATE Do something
    \ELSIF{$viewingtime$ in $trainingset$ is $==$ 0}
        \STATE Do something
    \ENDIF
\ENDFOR
\RETURN A, B
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Which ends up in:

[image]

I can not find out why there is no indention visible.
In my cls file I have imported the following packages:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

Comment: I get a different output if I complete your snippets to a minimal document. Using `\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{STEP 1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE Something
\FOR{\textbf{each} $user$}
    \IF{A in B is $>$ 0}
        \STATE Do something
    \ELSIF{$viewingtime$ in $trainingset$ is $==$ 0}
        \STATE Do something
    \ENDIF
\ENDFOR
\RETURN A, B
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}` I get this: http://i.imgur.com/L5ihhtE.png Do you get no indention using my complete minimal document?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yep! Still no indention. Perhaps important to note is that I use sharelatex to compile. If I try to your minimal example with this sig-alternate [template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/association-for-computing-machinery-(acm)-sig-proceedings-alternate) I get not indention. Perhaps the properties within that templates force the algorithm to not indent but I can not find it.

Comment: It seems then that ShareLaTeX is using a different version of `sig-alternate` than the one in my system. I am using `sig-alternate.cls    2012/05/23 - V2.5 - based on acmproc.cls V1.3 <Nov. 30 '99>` and get the indentation in the image I linked to.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible that you can share your cls file with me? So that I can test whether the cls file is the issue or that sharelatex is messing up the format? @GonzaloMedina

Comment: Sure. Follow this link http://pastebin.com/z6E0xfDy to find the `.cls` I used.

Comment: I am sorry! But could you post it again? I did not had the time to retrieve the file. @GonzaloMedina